# Magento 2 avoid customer direct login after click confirmation email

Tags: email, magento2.4.1, confirmation

Now my customer directly login after click confirm the email, i want if customer click the
confirmation mail after need to login.

Answer (score 0):

Please set yes in the below configuration in your admin panel, first log in to the admin panel of your Magento and go to

```
Store menu->Configuration->Customer Configuration -> Create New Account
```

Field name: Require Emails Confirmation.

Set the drop-down menu to Yes to enable email verification and click on the Save Configuration.
After saving configuration you need to clear your Magento cache and check
Hope it will work.....

Comment: After this customer gets email confirmation right? If the customer clicks the email confirmation link it redirects to our website and directly going to my account page, i need if the customer clicks the email confirmation redirects to the login page. How to achieve this?